# Socket.IO bare-bones no-method objects or fully-equipped class-based objects for client updates?

Tags: node.js, performance, io, socket.io, processing-efficiency

Say I have an array of `players` in my Node app, each `player` being an object. Every tick, I send my array to my clients, with Socket.IO. I'm not sure, out of the two following methods, would be the most efficient way of doing this:

1. For each `player`, I add a basic object to my array, such as `{id:1,x:10,y:20,color:"#000000"}`. Then I can send the whole array, raw, to my clients. Functions that I need are non-object specific and handle the parsed object. This options is used in this [Agar.io clone](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone).
2. For each `player`, I add an object based on a `Player` class, like `{id:1,x:10,y:20,color:"#000000",update:function(){//code},someOtherFunction:function(){//code}}` and then create a pseudo array of pseudo objects (like the one in option **1**) to send to my players each tick.

If there are any better alternatives, please outline them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data stored in  your app should be optimized for best coding style.  That means it should be readable, maintainable, extensible, robust, etc...

Data sent via a transport should be optimized for most efficient transport.

One should not really influence or drive the other.  If the two separate priorities lead to different formats, then you simply convert from one to the other before sending data or when receiving data.

---

Given all that, I would think that you would want to use object oriented principles within your app so that a player could be an actual object with methods.

Then, when you want to send data across the wire, you just pull out whatever data you want to send, format it into something that is efficient for transport and send it.  The receiver will then parse the data and insert it into an object.

Comment: That's basically the format that I have now. I'm just worried about the time cost, especially considering that I might have in excess of thousands of objects. What you're saying does make sense. Just one question: does having a method for every object mean less efficiency (and more memory usage) than having one function that you can parse an object to? Example: `obj = {key:"value",method:function(){}};obj.method();` vs. `obj = {key:"value"};method = function(object){/*do something to object*/};method(object);`.

Comment: @Mirabilis - If you use object prototypes, then there is only one actual function for all your objects.  That's a reason to use the prototype mechanism.  If you assign methods manually in each object constructor or in a factory function, then it creates a new function instance for each object which is not as light on memory usage.  Abstract questions like this are much harder to answer than real questions containing real code.  If you show your real code, we can tell you exactly where you can improve memory usage or network bandwidth rather than discussing it so theoretically.